# electron build error when using robot-js on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am trying to use robot-js with Electron, but when I try to start my app I get the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAn0x.jpg

Cannot find module "./win32-x64-54"

Without robot-js my app runs fine. I am using robot-js version 1.0.2 and have the windows-build-tools installed.

EDIT: This problem only occurs with Electron, in a standard Node-Project the robot-js runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a .npmrc file and npm rebuild solved my issue, see here: https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1259#issuecomment-289600717